# Add cell, but don`t dismiss keyboard - CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have a problem. I have a collection view, in section 0 you can see item what you put there, in section 1, there is an add button like this:

[image]

I want, when I click on plus button add a cell and start editing (`cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder`))), then change collectionView sectionInset, it works. But when I click plus button, the keyboard call notif(DidKeyboardShow), so content is .zero, then keyboard appear and sectionInset is where I want. How can I behave problem? I don't want to dismiss the keyboard. I want to appear it.

Comment: Keyboard disappear when you add a cell right?

Comment: yes keyboard send notification observer... But I want when cell appear start typing, so the function is becomeFirstResponder

Comment: i think you need to fetch the particular text field of the particular section and make him first responder. After reloading

Comment: I get the new cell becomeFirstResponder, but the previous cell post the notification like dissmisKeyboard, but keyboard is still visible, so is any way to behave dismiss keyboard? I want only dismiss keyboard, when I click on view or somewhere.

Comment: You need to call resignFirstResponder or self.view.endEditing(true) for dismiss the keyboard

Comment: But I want to dismiss the keyboard at the end. Before that, I want to click on the button and don't call dissmisKeyboard, what call when I click on another text field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177669/discussion-between-david-kadlcek-and-shivi-shub).